# How to return an html file in bottle server?

Tags: python, bottle

So I have a bottle web framework running but I would like to have one webpage in it.

I have already created the webpage in html and css but I'm not sure how to make bottle use it.
I have it displaying just the html but the css part of it does not work.

I've tried googling around but I can't seem to find an example of this.

```
@get('/test')
def test():
    return static_file('index.html' , root="views")
```

My css files are in the same directory as the views folder.

Comment: Are you talking about the bottle framework?

Comment: yes, I'll add that to the main question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
from bottle import static_file


@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/your/static/files')
```

This is the code that the Bottle docs give for serving a static file.

Comment: I know how do to that and it returns my html and it works fine but my css doesn't work. Which is my main concern.

Comment: @Ramis Is your .css file also in the same directory? Posting the code you are using to call `static_file()` and description of the folder hierarchy would make it easier to debug.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: Thanks, using static file I figured out that I had to make a route to my css and images files. After that everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Bottle is best suited for APIs, where routes don't return HTML files. However, you can serve static HTML files with the `static_file` function.

If you're looking for a more comprehensive framework with HTML templating, try [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Yea, it was the reason I choose bottle at the beginning but I now need one webpage with my api. I don't really have the time to change the web framework.

Answer (score 0):

In case we have different folders for js and css files (being used in html files) which is general case in all projects, we need to explicitly serve js and css directory contents separately.

Refer below code for further details:

```
from bottle import route
from bottle import static_file

#Hosts html file which will be invoked from browser.
@route('/filesPath/<staticFile>')
def serve_static_file(staticFile):
    filePath = '/path/to/your/static/file/'
    return static_file(staticFile, filePath)

#host css files which will be invoked implicitly by your html files.
@route('/files_path/css/<cssFile>')
def serve_css_files(cssFile):
    filePath = '/path/to/your/css/file/'
    return static_file(cssFile, filePath)

# host js files which will be invoked implicitly by your html files.
@route('/files_path/js/<jsFile>')
def serve_js_files(jsFile):
    filePath = '/path/to/your/jss/file/'
    return static_file(jsFile, filePath)
```